# Getting different HTTP responses in API integration tests based on where I place my breakpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api, xunit

I've been getting non-deterministic test results and decided to delve deeper into the issue. I've ended up on two tests behaving differently based on whether I *Debug* them, or just use *Run*. I've managed to magically fix one by deleting and renaming it.

I'm testing my API endpoint for updating usernames via `WebApplicationFactory`(I'm using Mediator and a RavenDb that I recreate between every test if that makes a difference). The problem test case is `User_Can_Not_Update_Username_If_It_Is_Already_Taken()`. I'm expecting a *Conflict* response, but most of the time I'm getting *OK*. The weirdest thing is that the response varies on where I put my breakpoint:
[OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQSPu.png)
[Conflict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AumPh.png).

I've tried clearing Rider cache and looking into my `FakeApp` not disposing correctly. Trying to *Debug* before the `UpdateUsernameCommandHandler`results in the `Conflict` response status code, so I'm really at loss right now.

Here is the code of the test case:

```
        [Fact]
        public async Task User_Can_Not_Update_Username_If_It_Is_Already_Taken()
        {
            // Arrange
            using var app = new FakeApp(DatabaseFixture.TestDbName);
            var registerUserCommand = new RegisterUserCommand
            {
                Email = "oleksandr.torianyk@gmail.com"
            };
            var registerUserStringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(registerUserCommand);
            var registerUserHttpContent = new StringContent(registerUserStringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var registerUserResponse = await app.Client.PostAsync("/user", registerUserHttpContent);

            var initialUpdateUsernameCommand = new UpdateUsernameCommand
            {
                Id = new Guid(await registerUserResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()),
                Username = "All-ToR"
            };
            var initialUpdateUsernameStringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(initialUpdateUsernameCommand);
            var initialUpdateUsernameHttpContent = new StringContent(initialUpdateUsernameStringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            await app.Client.PutAsync("/user/username", initialUpdateUsernameHttpContent);

            var updateUsernameCommand = new UpdateUsernameCommand
            {
                Id = new Guid(await registerUserResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()),
                Username = "All-ToR"
            };
            var updateUsernameStringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updateUsernameCommand);
            var updateUsernameHttpContent = new StringContent(updateUsernameStringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            
            // Act
            var response = await app.Client.PutAsync("/user/username", updateUsernameHttpContent);

            // Assert
            response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
        }
```

FakeApp

```
    public class FakeApp : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _appFactory;

        public HttpClient Client { get; }

        public FakeApp(string ravenDbName = default)
        {
            _appFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>().WithWebHostBuilder(webHostBuilder =>
                webHostBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", true)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                        .Build();

                    services.AddRavenDb(configuration, ravenDbName);
                    services.AddDependencies();
                    services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                }));

            Client = _appFactory.CreateClient();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Client.Dispose();
            _appFactory.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: HOw do you know it's a problem of the Test and not FakeApp ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have a dozen similar tests using FakeApp and all of them seem to pass. Perhaps you are right though, I'll attach the code of FakeApp to the question.